# Android: Async Task with Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I am developing an application in which what I done is:

In `onCreate()` I first called a Async Task and then write a thread as:

```
new LoadDataBase().execute();

// New Thread call.
new Thread() {          
    // Running Thread.
    public void run() {
        int count=0;    
        while (count<5){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
                count++;
            }catch(Throwable e){   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   

        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this,ActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}.start();
```

My Async Task Code is as follows:

```
private class LoadDataBase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ 
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // Create data base from assets folder.
        DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            dataBaseHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Closing the Data base.
        dataBaseHelper.close();
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}
}
```

But the issue is that my thread is not working properly. Means I want that the Activity one should wait for some time then activity two invoke. But it is not happing.

As I run my app, activity one is visible for fraction on second and activity two is occurs. It happens so fast that the user is not able to find that activity one is there in the app or not. But the other functionality is working fine.

Now what should I do now to hold my activity one. I don't want to implement progress dialog in Async Task because I already implemented it in XML file.

Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

In `onPostExecute(String result) Method`, Write waiting time code using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but can you elaborate it in detail that how to write waiting time code using Handler.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=handler+example+in+android&oq=handler&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4695j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8